# Using regex to remove the unnecessary whitespace to get the expected output

Tags: python, regex

I have a few unstructured data like this

```
test1     21;
 test2  22;
test3    [ 23 ];
```

and I want to remove the unnecessary whitespace and convert it into the list of two-item per row and the expected output should look like this

```
['test1', '21']
['test2', '22']
['test3', ['23']]
```

Now, I am using this regex `sub` method to remove the unnecessary whitespace

```
re.sub(r"\s+", " ", z.rstrip('\n').lstrip(' ').rstrip(';')).split(' ')
```

Now, the problem is that it is able to replace the unnecessary whitespace into single whitespace, which is fine. But the problem I am facing in the third example, where after and before the open and close bracket respectively, it has whitespace and that I what to remove. But using the above regex I am not able to.

This is the output currently I am getting

```
['test1', '21']
['test2', '22']
['test3', '[', '23', ']']
```

You may check the example here on [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/live.html#code=import%20re%0A%0Ax%20%3D%20%22test1%20%20%20%20%2021%22%0Ay%20%3D%20%22%20%20%20%20%20test2%20%2022%22%0Az%20%3D%20%22%20%20%20%20test3%20%20%20%20%5B%2023%20%5D%22%0A%0Araw%20%3D%20re.sub%28r%22%5Cs%2B%22,%20%22%20%22,%20z.rstrip%28%27%5Cn%27%29.lstrip%28%27%20%27%29.rstrip%28%27%3B%27%29%29.split%28%27%20%27%29%0A%0Aprint%28raw%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Comment: Why not remove the square brackets before?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. actually I need those square brackets. Let me update the post. Sorry again.

Comment: This is not a possible outcome with regex, since `['23']` is a result of making an array. Not really a regex strong point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
 
x = "test1     21"
y = "     test2  22"
z = "    test3    [ 23 ]"
 
for a in [x, y, z]:
    print(re.sub(r"(?<![^[\s])\s+|\s+(?=])", "", a.rstrip('\n').lstrip(' ').rstrip(';')).split(' '))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/viEX7B). Output:

```
['test1', '21']
['test2', '22']
['test3', '[23]']
```

*Details*:

- `(?<![^[\s])\s+` - one or more whitespaces that are preceded with a `[` char, whitespace or start of string
- `|` - or
- `\s+(?=])` - one or more whitespaces that are followed with a `]` char.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with 2 capture groups:

```
(\w+)\s+(\[[^]]+\]|\w+);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1jGi8b/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters in first capture group
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(\[[^]]+\]|\w+)`: Match a `[...]` string or a word in second capture group
- `;`: Match a `;`

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import re
>>> data = '''
... test1     21;
...  test2  22;
... test3    [ 23 ];
... '''
>>> res = []
>>>
>>> for i in re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+(\[[^]]+\]|\w+);', data):
...     res.append([ i[0], eval(re.sub(r'^(\[)\s*|\s*(\])$', r'\1"\2', i[1])) if i[1].startswith('[') else i[1] ])
...
>>> print (res)
[['test1', '21'], ['test2', '22'], ['test3', ['23']]]
```